# Charge conjugation is a symmetry for the quantized free Dirac action?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, dirac-equation, charge-conjugation, cpt-symmetry

I am self-studying QFT on "A modern introduction to quantum filed theory" by Maggiore, and on page 95 he states: "For the free Dirac action, one immediately sees that C,P and T are indeed symmetry operation", but I am having an hard time to realize what seems to be immediate.

Also in Peskin&Schroeder's book "Introduction on quantum field theory" at page 71 mention that free Dirac Lagrangian is invariant under C symmetry but there's no proof.

I can find on internet proof for the C invariance of the **classical** free Dirac Lagrangian, but nothing for the quantized one.

I have done some calculation and I have been able to prove the following
$$
C\bar\Psi\Psi C=\bar\Psi\Psi
$$

$$
C(\bar\Psi \gamma^\mu \Psi)C=-\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu\Psi
$$

Note that to prove both I had to use the anticommutator:

$$
\{\Psi_a(t,\vec{x}),\bar\Psi_b(t,\vec{y})\}=\delta(\vec x-\vec y)\gamma^0_{ab}
$$

The Lagrangian density is:

$$
\mathcal{L}=\bar\Psi(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\Psi=i\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\Psi -m\bar\Psi\Psi
$$

Now as far as I can see to calculate $C\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\Psi C$ I can't use the same steps used to prove $C(\bar\Psi \gamma^\mu \Psi)C=-\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu\Psi$ cause I don't know what is $\{\partial_\mu\Psi_a(t,\vec{x}),\bar\Psi_b(t,\vec{y})\}$.

So I am really confused about what I am misunderstanding and what I am doing wrong or unnecessary complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charge conjugation leaves spacetime coordinates and Dirac matrices alone, and acts only on the spinor structure of $\Psi$, meaning that
$$
{\cal{C}}\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\right)\Psi{\cal{C}}^\dagger=\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\right){\cal{C}}\Psi{\cal{C}}^\dagger \ . 
$$
Using
$$
{\cal{C}}\Psi{\cal{C}}^\dagger=i\gamma^2\Psi^*=i\gamma^2\gamma^0\overline{\Psi}^T \ ,
$$
$$
{\cal{C}}\Psi^\dagger{\cal{C}}^\dagger=i\Psi^T\gamma^2 \ \ , \ \
{\cal{C}}\overline{\Psi}{\cal{C}}^\dagger=i\Psi^T\gamma^2\gamma^0 \ ,
$$
and
$$
\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0=\gamma^{\mu \, \dagger} \ \ , \ \ 
\gamma^2\gamma^\mu\gamma^2=\gamma^{\mu \, *} \ ,
$$
we find
$$
{\cal{C}}\overline{\Psi}\Psi{\cal{C}}^\dagger={\cal{C}}\overline{\Psi}{\cal{C}}^\dagger{\cal{C}}\Psi{\cal{C}}^\dagger=-\Psi^T\overline{\Psi}^T=-\Psi_\alpha\overline{\Psi}_\alpha \ ,
$$
$$
{\cal{C}}\overline{\Psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\right)\Psi{\cal{C}}^\dagger={\cal{C}}\overline{\Psi}{\cal{C}}^\dagger\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\right){\cal{C}}\Psi{\cal{C}}^\dagger=\Psi^T\left(i\gamma^{\mu \, T}\partial_\mu\right)\overline{\Psi}^T=
\Psi_\alpha\left(i\left(\gamma^{\mu}\right)_{\beta\alpha}\partial_\mu\overline{\Psi}_\beta\right) \ .
$$
Now we have to "pull" $\overline{\Psi}$ to the left. The anticommutator of two fermion field operators (or their derivatives) is problematic when evaluated at the very same spacetime point, but note that in its second quantized definition, the Lagrangian is normal ordered (it is defined like that exactly to cancel these ill-defined constants). Within normal ordering (denoted as $:(...):$), all fermion field operators anticommute without additional terms:
$$
:\Psi_\alpha\overline{\Psi}_\beta: \, =- \, :\overline{\Psi}_\beta\Psi_\alpha: \ \ , \ \
:\Psi_\alpha\left(\partial_\mu\overline{\Psi}_\beta\right): \, =- \, :\left(\partial_\mu\overline{\Psi}_\beta\right)\Psi_\alpha:=- \, :\overline{\Psi}_\beta\overset{\leftarrow}{\partial_\mu}\Psi_\alpha: \ ,
$$
leading to
$$
{\cal{C}}:\overline{\Psi}\Psi:{\cal{C}}^\dagger= \, :\overline{\Psi}\Psi: \ \ , \ \
{\cal{C}}:\overline{\Psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\right)\Psi:{\cal{C}}^\dagger=-:\overline{\Psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\overset{\leftarrow}{\partial_\mu}\right)\gamma^\mu\Psi: \ .
$$
If we define the Lagrangian as
$$
{\cal{L}}'= \, :\overline{\Psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\overset{\rightarrow}{\partial_\mu}-m\right)\Psi: \ ,
$$
then charge conjugation would transform this into
$$
{\cal{C}}{\cal{L}}'{\cal{C}}^\dagger= \, :\overline{\Psi}\left(-i\gamma^\mu\overset{\leftarrow}{\partial_\mu}-m\right)\Psi: \ .
$$
The difference between this and the original Lagrangian is just an uninteresting total derivative:
$$
\overline{\Psi}i\gamma^\mu\overset{\rightarrow}{\partial_\mu}\Psi=-\overline{\Psi}i\gamma^\mu\overset{\leftarrow}{\partial_\mu}\Psi + \, \text{total derivative} \ ,
$$
meaning that ${\cal{L}}'$ and ${\cal{C}}{\cal{L}}'{\cal{C}}^\dagger$ are essentially equal. We can make this symmetry more manifest by defining the Lagrangian alternatively (but equivalently) as
$$
{\cal{L}}=\, :\overline{\Psi}\left(\frac{i}{2}\gamma^\mu\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_\mu}-m\right)\Psi: \ ,
$$
where $\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_\mu}=\overset{\rightarrow}{\partial_\mu}-\overset{\leftarrow}{\partial_\mu}$. This choice shows
$$
{\cal{C}}{\cal{L}}{\cal{C}}^\dagger={\cal{L}}
$$
explicitly.

Comment: Wonderful! I was about to give up, I would never have gotten that far. I'm consoled by the fact that it wasn't as immediate as they want to imply in the books

Comment: It is covered in this detail in some book you are familiar with?

Comment: @Andrea Thanks for the feedback. This is indeed not as trivial as implied in the text. If I recall correctly, this is covered in *Relativistic Quantum Mechanics and Field Theory* by Gross.